# Здравствуйте, помогите пожайлуста с оптимизацией кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, оптимизация

```
def bp1():
  bpnumber(1)
def bp2():
  bpnumber(2)
def bp3():
  bpnumber(3)
def bp4():
  bpnumber(4)
def bp5():
  bpnumber(5)
def bp6():
  bpnumber(6)
def bp7():
  bpnumber(7)
def bp8():
  bpnumber(8)
def bp9():
  bpnumber(9)
def bp0():
  bpnumber(0)

def bpnumber(number):
  функция





ui.b1.clicked.connect(bp1)
ui.b2.clicked.connect(bp2)
ui.b3.clicked.connect(bp3)
ui.b4.clicked.connect(bp4)
ui.b5.clicked.connect(bp5)
ui.b6.clicked.connect(bp6)
ui.b7.clicked.connect(bp7)
ui.b8.clicked.connect(bp8)
ui.b9.clicked.connect(bp9)
ui.b0.clicked.connect(bp0)
```

Comment: А по каким критериям вы хотите оптимизировать? Сейчас код оптимизирован по скорости выполнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы наверное хотите поменьше текста? Попробуйте пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize   

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

        self.numButton = 1
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    

        pybutton = QPushButton('Создать кнопку', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)

        self.lay = QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)        
        self.lay.addWidget(pybutton)
        self.lay.addStretch(1)

    def clickMethod(self):
        newBtn = QPushButton('Кнопка {}'.format(self.numButton), self)
        self.numButton += 1
        newBtn.clicked.connect(lambda text: print("\nВы кликнули -> `{}`".format(newBtn.text())))
        self.lay.addWidget(newBtn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> void QAbstractButton::clicked(bool checked = false)
>
> Этот сигнал испускается, когда кнопка активирована (то есть нажата, затем отпущена, 
>   когда курсор мыши находится внутри кнопки), когда нажата клавиша быстрого вызова 
>   или когда вызывается click() или animateClick().

Нужно при клике что-то передать в вызываемый метод, 
чтобы дальше выполнять что надо.
Один из вариантов передачи, использование функции `lambda`. Пробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize   

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

        self.numButton = 1
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    

        pybutton = QPushButton('Создать кнопку', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)

        self.lay = QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)        
        self.lay.addWidget(pybutton)
        self.lay.addStretch(1)

    def clickMethod(self):
        newBtn = QPushButton('Кнопка {}'.format(self.numButton), self)
        self.numButton += 1
#        newBtn.clicked.connect(lambda text: print("\nВы кликнули -> `{}`".format(newBtn.text())))
        newBtn.clicked.connect(lambda checked, text=newBtn.text(): self.bpnumber(text))
        self.lay.addWidget(newBtn)

    def bpnumber(self, textButton):
        print("Вы кликнули -> `{}`".format(textButton))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: Можно пожайлуста комментарии к коду

Comment: @ВадимАнтонюк я добавил пример и некоторые комментарии.

Answer (score -1):

```
def bp(num):
  bpnumber(num)

ui.b1.clicked.connect(bp(1))
ui.b2.clicked.connect(bp(2))
и т.д.
```

Наверное, можно последние строчки засунуть в список и сделать просто цикл, чтобы не писать одно и то же много раз, но не буду советовать, не видя остальной код.

Да и вообще функцию `bp()` можно убрать за ненадобностью, а сделать просто

```
def bpnumber(number):
  функция

ui.b1.clicked.connect(bpnumber(1))
ui.b2.clicked.connect(bpnumber(2))
```

Comment: цикл - потеря скорости.

Comment: такой вариант не работает

Comment: @nick_n_a Сколько? 24 наносекунды?

Comment: @ВадимАнтонюк "не работает" - бесполезный комментарий, т.е. совершенно неясно, что не работает, как именно не работает, и т.п.. У меня работает.

Comment: функция не запускается

Comment: Точно такой же бесполезный комментарий. Что означает "не запускается"?